# Can a method contained in an abstract class be considered polymorphic?

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract

When looking at the following code, each of the methods in each of the classes is considered polymorphic.

```
class A {
void foo() {}
}

class B extends A {
void foo() {}
}

class C extends A {
void foo() {}
}
```

Is it still the case in the following snippet, where class A is abstract?

```
abstract class A {
void foo() {}
}

class B extends A {
void foo() {}
}

class C extends A {
void foo() {}
}
```

I am working on this with a study group for the java certification exam, and I thought that it would not be.  Because you could still access foo() in A if you were to extend class D but not define foo(), and thereafter attempt to access it.  In such a case it wouldn't be polymorphic because there would be no change to it.

```
abstract class A {
void foo() {}
}

class D extends A {
}
```

Comment: What do you think? Why do you think so? What is `abstract`?

Comment: Read through the other answer, and my question was incorrect as it was, thanks for the instruction!